# Are there any automake m4 macros for flymake mode?

Tags: emacs, automake, flymake

EmacsWiki (in http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FlyMake) has a recommendation to create a flymake.mk file and include it in every Makefile if you are using Automake, but this doesn't seem very... Automake-y and I assume that having a standard m4 macro for this would be a better solution.  I was wondering if anyone had seen such a beast in the wild before I go off and take a whack at building one myself.